# Conditional expectation of product of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

I did not find the following question addressed nor a counterexample or proof.

For a continious martingale does,

$\mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{s} \mid \mathcal{F}_{u})=X_{u}\mathbb{E}(X_{s} \mid \mathcal{F}_{u})$

hold for $s,t>u$?

In other words can we apply the martingale property to get a measurable function and pull it out via the property of the conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, we have $\mathbb{E}(X_s \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = X_u$ and therefore your assertion is equivalent to

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t X_s \mid \mathcal{F}_u )=  X_u^2.\tag{1}$$

Note that $(1)$ implies, in particular,

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t X_s) = \mathbb{E}(X_u^2) \qquad \text{for all} \, \, u<s,t.$$

This equation does, in general, fail to hold true and hence $(1)$ does, in general, not hold true. Consider for instance a one-dimensional Brownian motion $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, then $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale with continuous sample paths and

$$\min\{s,t\} = \mathbb{E}(X_s X_t) \neq \mathbb{E}(X_u^2) = u$$

for any $u<s,t$.

**Remark:** Using the tower property it is not difficult to see that $$\mathbb{E}(X_s X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = \mathbb{E}(X_s^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_u) \qquad \text{for all} \, \, u \leq s \leq t.$$ This means that $(1)$ is actually equivalent to saying that $(X_t^2)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. As $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ being a martingale does clearly **not** imply that $(X_t^2)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, we cannot expect that $(1)$ holds.